# How to integration test Azure Web Jobs?

Tags: azure, integration-testing, azure-storage, azure-webjobs

I have a ASP.NET Web API application with supporting Azure Web Job with functions that are triggered by messages added to a storage queue by the API's controllers. Testing the Web API is simple enough using OWIN but how do I test the web jobs?

Do I run a console app in memory in the test runner? Execute the function directly (that wouldn't be a proper integration test though)? It is a continious job so the app doesn't exit. To make matters worse Azure Web Job-functions are void so there's no output to assert.

Comment: From code functionality testing perspective i would say is you can unit test the function inside the WebJob void method which is anyways a entry point where you should not be having lot of code. If you want to really do integration testing than add a condition in your code to output the response to some datastore which eventually can be asserted. Of course this is just for test messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @boris-lipschitz is correct, when your job is continious (as op says it is), you can't do anything after calling host.RunAndBlock().

However, if you run the host in a separate thread, you can continue with the test as desired. Although, you have to do some kind of polling in the end of the test to know when the job has run.

**Example**
*Function to be tested (A simple copy from one blob to another, triggered by created blob):*

```
public void CopyBlob(
    [BlobTrigger("input/{name}")] TextReader input,
    [Blob("output/{name}")] out string output)
{
    output = input.ReadToEnd();
}
```

*Test function:*

```
[Test]
public void CopyBlobTest()
{
    var blobClient = GetBlobClient("UseDevelopmentStorage=true;");

    //Start host in separate thread
    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
        var host = new JobHost();
        host.RunAndBlock();
    });

    thread.Start();

    //Trigger job by writing some content to a blob
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var stringWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        stringWriter.Write("TestContent");
        stringWriter.Flush();

        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        blobClient.UploadStream("input", "blobName", stream);
    }

    //Check every second for up to 20 seconds, to see if blob have been created in output and assert content if it has
    var maxTries = 20;
    while (maxTries-- > 0)
    {
        if (!blobClient.Exists("output", "blobName"))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            continue;
        }

        using (var stream = blobClient.OpenRead("output", "blobName"))
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("TestContent", streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can no longer new up a `JobHost` like this anymore (at least in .NET Core 2.1). The newish way is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/3eb3dc7a5d1d6e51c6edad4cdcaa1d6b553084e4/sample/SampleHost/Program.cs) (see also [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1871#issuecomment-423701576) for more of the convo).

Comment: Hi, How does it work when your method "CopyBlob" become Async? out parameters are not allowed in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to run console app in memory. You can run JobHost in the memory of your integration test.

```
var host = new JobHost();
```

You could use host.Call() or host.RunAndBlock(). You would need to point to Azure storage account as webjobs are not supported in localhost.
It depends on what your function is doing, but you could manually add a message to a queue, add a blob or whatever. You could assert by querying the storage where your webjob executed result, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to simulate this really easily by simply doing the following, and it seems to work fine for me:

```
private JobHost _webJob;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void StartupFixture()
{
     _webJob = Program.GetHost();
     _webJob.Start();
}
[OneTimeTearDown]
public void TearDownFixture()
{
    _webJob?.Stop();
}
```

Where the WebJob Code looks like:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var host = GetHost();
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }

    public static JobHost GetHost() 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```