# How to do Integration Tests for Azure Webjobs V3?

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration-testing, azure-webjobs

Azure Webjob is now on V3, so this answer is not up to date anymore ([How to integration test Azure Web Jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299808/how-to-integration-test-azure-web-jobs/39322363#39322363))

I imagine we need to do something like this:

```
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            using (host)
            {
                var jobHost = host.Services.GetService(typeof(IJobHost)) as JobHost;
                var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    // parameters of MyQueueTriggerMethodAsync
                };

                await host.StartAsync();
                await jobHost.CallAsync("MyQueueTriggerMethodAsync", arguments);
                await host.StopAsync();
            }
```

QueueTrigger Function

```
    public MyService(
        ILogger<MyService> logger
    )
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task MyQueueTriggerMethodAsync(
        [QueueTrigger("MyQueue")] MyObj obj
    )
    {
        _logger.Log("ReadFromQueueAsync success");
    }
```

But after that, how can I see what's happened?

What do you suggest to be able to do Integration Tests for Azure Webjobs V3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a cross post [with Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2310). The product team recommends looking at their own end-to-end testing for ideas on how to handle integration testing.

To summarize:

You [can configure](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.EndToEndTests/AzureStorageEndToEndTests.cs#L534-L545) an `IHost` as a `TestHost` and add your integrated services to it.

```
public TestFixture()
{
     IHost host = new HostBuilder()
         .ConfigureDefaultTestHost<TestFixture>(b =>
         {
              b.AddAzureStorage();
         })
         .Build();

         var provider = host.Services.GetService<StorageAccountProvider>();
         StorageAccount = provider.GetHost().SdkObject;
}
```

Tests would look something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Covers:
/// - queue binding to custom object
/// - queue trigger
/// - table writing
/// </summary>
public static void QueueToICollectorAndQueue(
    [QueueTrigger(TestQueueNameEtag)] CustomObject e2equeue,
    [Table(TableName)] ICollector<ITableEntity> table,
    [Queue(TestQueueName)] out CustomObject output)
{
    const string tableKeys = "testETag";

    DynamicTableEntity result = new DynamicTableEntity
    {
        PartitionKey = tableKeys,
        RowKey = tableKeys,
        Properties = new Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>()
        {
            { "Text", new EntityProperty("before") },
            { "Number", new EntityProperty("1") }
        }
    };

    table.Add(result);

    result.Properties["Text"] = new EntityProperty("after");
    result.ETag = "*";
    table.Add(result);

    output = e2equeue;
}
```

The difficulty in setting up a specific test depends on which triggers and outputs you are using and whether or not an emulator.

Comment: Exact, I asked to both place :) Thanks, I will validate your answer